# Aggregate by property on parent document with Elasticsearch join field

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an Elasticsearch index that uses a [join type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/parent-join.html) field to relate two types of indexed documents to each other via a parent-child relation: `posts` which are parents of `comments`.

`posts` have a `category` keyword field, and `comments` belong to `posts`. I would like to find the **number of `comments` in each post `category`**, like so:

```json
// what query do I need to get this result?

{
  "aggregations" : {
    "comment-counts-by-post-category" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Dogs",
          "doc_count" : 2,
        },
        {
          "key" : "Cats",
          "doc_count" : 1,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a complete example:

I have an index with the following mapping:

```json
PUT posts-index/
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "post": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "category": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "text": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "post_comment_join": {
                "type": "join",
                "relations": {
                    "post": "comment"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create two posts, one in the `Dogs` category, and one in the `Cats` category:

```json
PUT posts-index/_doc/post-1
{
    "text": "this is a dog post",
    "post": {
        "category": "Dogs"
    },
    "post_comment_join": {
        "name": "post"
    }
}

PUT posts-index/_doc/post-2
{
    "text": "this is a cat post",
    "post": {
        "category": "Cats"
    },
    "post_comment_join": {
        "name": "post"
    }
}
```

Then, I create a few comments (in this case, 2 on the dog post and 1 on the cat post)

```json
PUT posts-index/_doc/comment-1&routing=1&refresh
{
    "text": "this is comment 1 for post 1",
    "post_comment_join": {
        "name": "comment",
        "parent": "post-1"
    }
}

PUT posts-index/_doc/comment-2&routing=1&refresh
{
    "text": "this is comment 2 for post 1",
    "post_comment_join": {
        "name": "comment",
        "parent": "post-1"
    }
}

PUT posts-index/_doc/comment-3&routing=1&refresh
{
    "text": "this is a comment 1 for post 2",
    "post_comment_join": {
        "name": "comment",
        "parent": "post-2"
    }
}
```

I can search for all `comment` documents using a `has_parent` query:

```json
POST post-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "post",
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [ /* returns the 3 comments */ ]
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out how to do is find the **number of comments in each category**

I've looked into [Parent Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-parent-aggregation.html), but they seem to only allow you aggregate based on the `type` of the parent. In this case, all parents are of type `post`, so that doesn't help.

I've also tried using a basic `terms` aggregation using the [`join_field#parent_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_queries_and_aggregations) syntax:

```json
POST post-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "post",
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "agg-by-post-category": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "post_comment_join#post.category"
            }
        }
    }
}

// returns { "buckets": [] } in the aggs
```

Unfortunately, this returns no results. It seems as though the `post_comment_join#post` syntax can be used to aggregate *by parent doc*, but not by an *attribute* on the parent doc. (i.e., by the `_id` field of a `post`, but not by `post.category`)

Can anyone help me figure out the right `aggs` syntax to return all comments grouped by their parent post's category?

Again, here is the result I'm looking for:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "comment-counts-by-post-category" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Dogs",
          "doc_count" : 2,
        },
        {
          "key" : "Cats",
          "doc_count" : 1,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

##### Platform details

Amazon Opensearch service version 7.9

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of below two to find count of comments by category.

```
GET posts-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "comment",
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": false,
        "size": 0
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET posts-index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "top-tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "post.category",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "to-answers": {
          "children": {
            "type": "comment" 
          },
          "aggs": {
            "comments-count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```